# Count a total price of selected checkboxes

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

I have this section of code:

```
<form action="{{ URL::action('server-shop-post') }}" method="post" id="cart">
    <table class="table table-responsive">
        <thead>
            <tr><th>Check</th><th>Item</th><th>Pixel Points <span class="fa fa-cubes"></span></th></tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach($shopItems as $shopItem)
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @if(!in_array($shopItem -> id, $userPurchases))
                            <input form="cart" name="cart[]" value="{{ $shopItem -> id }}" type="checkbox">
                        @else
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>
                        @endif
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        {{ $shopItem -> name }}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        {{ $shopItem -> cost }}
                    </td>
                </tr>
            @endforeach
            <tr><td colspan="2">You have <span class="fa fa-cubes"></span> {{ Auth::user() -> pixel_points }}</td><td>Total cost: 200</td></tr>
        </tbody>
    </table><input type="submit">
</form>
```

What this does, is creates a table full of shop items and allows people to check the checkboxes to 'add to basket'. Then also the price is displayed in the same row as the check box. 
What I am aiming for is to have the user check an item, and the total cost update along with it. 
How can I add all the values together where the tick boxes are checked?

Comment: Take a look at this question. I proposed an answer there: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26702514/how-do-i-get-my-checkbox-values-and-option-values-to-add-up-and-enter-the-sum-in/26702588?noredirect=1#comment42018025_26702588][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26702514/how-do-i-get-my-checkbox-values-and-option-values-to-add-up-and-enter-the-sum-in/26702588?noredirect=1#comment42018025_26702588

Answer (score 2):

Iterating through all the list items might be costly if its a huge list.. so bind a "onchange" event handler to every checkbox.

```
$( ".aCommonClass" ).change(function() {
  //check if it was checked or unchecked.
  //based on that, add or sub the value from the total 
});
```

Comment: Just like the other answer, wouldnt this rely on the value of the input being the price? Whereas I have the id.

Comment: Yea,It depends on your implementation. So lets say you are using ID as the value, Then add a "id" attribute to the cost such as, "cost_{{ $shopItem -> id }}", then using the above on change function, When there is a change. Pick the text value from the "cost_+$(this).val()", which is the 'id' of the cost.. then you can easily pick the data and add or subtract..remember to convert from text to number to add/sub...

Comment: I see what you're saying. However I use the ID in the form submission, I create an array with it.

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to use Javascript to iterate the table and add up the total amounts. I would probably use jQuery for this. Something like:

```
var total = 0;
$('input[name="cart[]"]').each(function(item){
    total += item.val();
}
```

This assumes that the input element contains the price in the "value" attribute.

Comment: I don't think its a good idea to iterate through the whole list.. because you can just add a event handler to the checkbox and manipulate the total based on if it was checked or unchecked.

Comment: I considered something similar, but I have the items ID in the value of the checkbox meaning I cannot do this?

Comment: @shakirthow Good point, I missed that in the question. I think your answer is better, but my approach might be useful to someone with a similar problem to OP, but who may be constrained by the need to calculate the full amount every time (or on demand)

Answer (score 0):

I have created a solution which works for my case. Really not sure how reliable it is, it appears to be working beautifully.

```
<script>

    var cartTotal = 0;
    var fieldId;

    $('.tickbox').change(function(){
        fieldId = $(this).val();
        var value = parseInt(document.getElementById(fieldId).innerHTML);
        if($(this).is(":checked")) {
            cartTotal += value;
            document.getElementById('cart-total').innerHTML = "Total cost: " + cartTotal;

        } else {
            cartTotal -= value;
            document.getElementById('cart-total').innerHTML = "Total cost: " + cartTotal;
        }
    });
</script>
```

I wish I could explain how it works, but I don't really know. I will mark the answers which helped me create my answer.